# XAMPP Access Forbidden [ubuntu]

Tags: apache, ubuntu, xampp

Yesterday I was able to completely normally use PHP and phpmyadmin with XAMPP and make apps. The only thing changed is that I restarted the computer. Now I start lampp like always

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

and I get

```
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

Maybe the apache is the problem I don't know. But when I open localhost in browser, I get

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I added 'Require all granted' to that httpd.conf file, and it didn't help, so something else must be going on. I tried a lot of other threads on forums, nothing helped.
Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What is your htdocs root directoy and what chmod is set there? and what user is apache running?

Answer (score 1):

It could be possibly because another instance of Apache is running on your system. Just try to close all intances via `sudo killall -9 apache2` and then try to start/restart the LAMPP. 
Most linux OS ships Apache as default server, so if you even haven't installed them, they might be running in your system.